# Why doesn't the installation of the mysql-server package create a root account?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, apt

It's not the *Why?* that matters. It's the [*How can I do it myself?*](https://serverfault.com/questions/352357/why-doesnt-the-installation-of-the-mysql-server-package-create-a-root-account#352376)

---

I'm using *Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server*. I just want to [install a MySQL server](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/mysql), but for some reason it wont let me. 
When I run `apt-get install mysql-server` everything works fine. At the end of the installation a modal window pops up an asks me to enter the `root` password. The only oddity here is that the encoding of the special chars (like the border of the modal window) is a bit messed up. But I assume that this isn't the major problem.

At the end of the installation MySQL starts automatically and everything works fine, until I try to login. `mysql -u root -p` prompts me to `Enter password:`. I enter the password I used during the installation and get this error:  `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`
When I try it with an empty password I get the same error, except of the `(using password: YES)` part which turns to `(using password: NO)`.

I did some Google research and already tried all that `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` thingy.

I also checked the mysql user table. The only entry is the `debian-sys-maint` user.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user;
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| Host      | User             | Password                                  | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | Event_priv | Trigger_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | x509_issuer | x509_subject | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | *A632698FAB70686111EB0BE3F732A4C244B6DE8C | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: It does create a root account. You should change the title of your question.

Comment: When I used this `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` thing and got into the MySQL user table it only showed me the `debian-sys-maint`, so I guessed a root user wasn't created.

If I'm not right, feel free to correct me.

Comment: The encoding of the window is a mess if you're using a terminal not in synch with the configuration of the linux box. If I use puTTY and configure translation to UTF-8, make sure LANG in Ubuntu is set to en_US.UTF-8 and TERM to screen it looks "good" for me. Otherwise you might have to play around with these variables LANG=en_US, TERM=vt100 for example. Try to see what works for you! To try out if you got the charset right you can test the dialogs with: `whiptail --yesno oink 10 20` for example.

Comment: Thank you, Mattias! I configured PuTTY and now everything looks good. But the login problem is (of course) still left.

Comment: @silvinci I didn't realize you actually looked at the user table. Sounds like your install didn't complete 100% successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Since we really have no root user, we need to make us one. MySQL creates maintaining user by default. It is called `debian-sys-maint`. You can find its password in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

1. `start mysql` - Start MySQL the [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) way, if you haven't done so far.
2. `vi /etc/mysql/debian.cnf` - You'll see a configuration file with some variables. We're looking for `password = ****************`.
3. `mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p` - You will be prompted to enter a password. Enter the password we just found out. Don't wonder, you won't see anything while you are typing. Hit Enter. Bazinga! We're in!
4. `use mysql` - Tell MySQL that we want to edit its own configuration database.
5. `SELECT * FROM user` - Just for testing. The only row you should see is the `debian-sys-maint`, the user you are using currently using. If you see more than one row in there you should stop immediately and leave a comment, so you don't break more than you fix.
6. `INSERT INTO user VALUES ('localhost','root',password('YourNewPasswordGoesHere'),'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','',0,0,0,0);` - Run this SQL-Query. It will insert the user `root` and grant it all permissions. Don't forget to change `'YourNewPasswordGoesHere'` to your desired password.
7. Do you get an error?

   - `ERROR 1136 (21501): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` - Looks like we're having too many or too less values for our new `root` user. Check the `SELECT * FROM user` command and make a copy of `debian-sys-maint`'s values. You'll just have to fix the amount of `'Y'`, `''` and `0`.
   - *A different error* - Stop immediately! Let us know more in the comments.
   - `Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)` - That's no error. That's pure success! You can prove it by `SELECT * FROM user;`. Continue with the next step.
8. `quit` - Close your current MySQL session. We're done here.
9. `stop mysql` and then `start mysql` - The changes need a restart to take effect.
10. `mysql -u root -p` - Enter your new password when you're prompted to. Hit Enter.
11. You're done!

If you're having any trouble, let us know and post comment.

---

I'd like to thank [MDMarra](https://serverfault.com/questions/352357/why-doesnt-the-installation-of-the-mysql-server-package-create-a-root-account#answer-352360) who gave me the necessary hint!

Answer (score 3):

If there really is no root user when you look at the user table, then something went wrong during your install. The first thing to try is

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure

If that does't work, then you can try

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES ('localhost','root',password('newpassword'),'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','',0,0,0,0);
INSERT INTO user VALUES ('127.0.0.1','root',password('newpassword'),'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','',0,0,0,0);
INSERT INTO user VALUES ('ebuntu','root',password('newpassword'),'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','',0,0,0,0);
flush privileges;
quit
killall mysqld
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Second set of commands shamelessly stolen from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6432028&postcount=7)

Comment: `ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` I guess there are too many `'Y'`?

Comment: I corrected the `'Y'` count and am going to test it now.

Comment: Yeah! Celebration! You gave me the right hint. I'll put an answer together.

Answer (score 1):

If debconf asks you for a password for a root user is because it tries to create the root account. If it doesn't is because there's an error, either on your system or in the packaged version you are using.

I don't have an ubuntu to check it, but you should look for similar issues on launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

## "ERROR 1136 (21501): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1":

- If you have got in with debian-sys-maint password and you get an error below.
- You can update existing root password:

> update user
>   set authentication_string = password('YourNewPasswordGoesHere')
>   where host = 'localhost'
>   and user = 'root';

- restart mysql and try again :)